# UIScrollView swipe with timer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have the following code that render scroll view inside table view with three pages, I want the pages to be changed each 5 seconds , how can I do that ?

```
        UITableViewCell *cell;

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: sliderIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:sliderIdentifier];
        }

        if (sliderItems != nil && sliderItems.count > 0) {

            UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
            scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;

            for (int i = 0; i <  sliderItems.count ; i++) {
                CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

                UIImageView *awesomeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];

                ItemResponse *test = [ItemResponse new];
                test = sliderItems[i];

                dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
                //this will start the image loading in bg
                dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

                    NSString *urlStr = test.listingImage;
                    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
                    //this will set the image when loading is finished
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        awesomeView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                        [scroll addSubview:awesomeView];

                        UILabel *iconAdLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
                        iconAdLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0 + (i * self.view.frame.size.width),130,self.view.frame.size.width,70);
                        iconAdLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
                        NSString *titleStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", test.listingTitle];
                        iconAdLabel.text = titleStr;
                        UIColor *color = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:@"#000000" alpha:0.6];
                        iconAdLabel.backgroundColor = color;
                        UIColor *textcolor = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:@"#ffffff" alpha:1.0];
                        iconAdLabel.textColor = textcolor;
                        iconAdLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
                        UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"NotoKufiArabic" size:14.0f];
                        iconAdLabel.font = font;
                        iconAdLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

                        [scroll addSubview:iconAdLabel];
                    });
                });

            }

            scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width *  sliderItems.count , 200);
            dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
            //this will start the image loading in bg
            dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
                });
            });
        }

        return cell;
```

Comment: Setup an NSTimer to call a function every 5 seconds, and change the content offset of the scrollView in that function. This will require your scrollView to be in a wider scope so that you can use it in both `cellForRow` and your new function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  a `NSTimer` object

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

with action

```
-(void)timerAction
{
   [scroll scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height) animated:YES];
}
```

Also you need to invalidate the timer Object when the ViewController Disappears. So if you have multiple cells , use an NSArray to keep track of the timer objects and invalidate when no longer needed `[timer invalidate]`